# PhpStorm tell view which object is being used

Tags: phpstorm

I got the following problem: In PhpStorm I made up my own little MVC framework. Now I wanted to know if there's any way I could tell the view which object/class object it gets from the controller, so it PhpStorm is able to auto-complete, give hints etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply declare the variables at the top of each view, using phpDoc's [`@var`](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/PHP/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.var.pkg.html):

```
<?php
$view->title = $view->controller->id;
```

compared to

```
<?php
/**
 * @var \Framework\View $view
 */

$view->title = $view->controller->id;
```

This form of doc can be used literally anywhere and is not limited to the top of files:

```
foreach ($collection as $item) {
    /* @var ItemClass $item */
    var_dump( $item->getProperty() );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that hint, but if I got like a model $homeViewController, which contains various different classes, then I'm messed, as PHP isn't strongly typed. right?

Comment: PHP isn't strongly typed per-se, in the sense that you can type juggle most things back and forth. You can still forcefully juggle a variable to be eg. an integer or a boolean. That being said, you can get auto completion for all classes by hinting the classes separated by a `|` character like so: `/* @var User|Group|Organization $model */`. If you are expecting a thousand different classes I suggest you just go with the outermost parent class: `/* @var Model $model */`.